# Error: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,Int)] does not take parameters

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

age.foreach(println)

```
1,5
2,25
3,30
```

Age has id and age. Now I have to create like
    If(age>=1 && age<10) "1-10"
    Else if(age >=10 && age<20) "10-20"
    Else "30+"

So the result for the above data should be

1, 1-10

2, 10-20

3, 30+

```
Val ager = age.map(x => (x(0),(If(x(1)>=1 && x(1)<10) "1-         10"
Else if(x(1) >=10 && x(1)<20) "10-20"
Else "30+")))
```

I am getting the below error:
Error: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String,Int)] does not take parameter

Kindly help me to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

tuple-elements are not access like `x(0)` but `x._1` etc

this should work:

```
val ager = age.map(x =>
  (x._1, (if (x._2 >= 1 && x._2 < 10) "1-         10"
  else if (x._2 >= 10 && x._2 < 20) "10-20"
  else "30+"))
)
```